# Second level cache - smart eviction on related entities

Tags: spring, hibernate, caching, ehcache

I'm fairly new to caching and would like to ask a simple question:

Imagine i have the following class entity:

```
@Entity
public class Player {

   @OneToOne
   private Secret secret;

}
```

now, lets assume i'm caching both entites (Secret and Player).
now, lets say i do this:

```
player.getSecret().setValue("no secrets");  // lets say this secret id == 2
playerRepository.save(player);
```

Does the 2nd level cache smart enough to evict the cache called "Secret" where an entry is with id == 2?

Does the 2nd level cache have some sort of limitation that i should be aware of ? will it be pluggable without changing my web app whats or ever?

Comment: Yes. Why don't you try it?

Comment: I edited my post, i was trying to ask in a more genralized way about pitfalls of 2nd level cache

Comment: The second-level cache is almost transparent. The only pitfalls I know about are that, if some other process updaters the database, the cache won't be aware of it (obviously), and that some join fetches are not always honored (unless this bug has been fixed sine I met it).

Answer (score 0):

It works well in that case, it will determine when objects are stale automatically if you use the correct cache concurrency strategy.

Concerning the question about pitfalls, these are some things to be aware when setting up the cache, that might be surprising the first time you see them:

- by default only entities loaded by Id are cached, if you want to cache query results you need to add the query cache as well.
- If you want to cache one to many to collections you need to annotate the association independently, as by default associations are not cached

See this blog post with details on these two caches: [Truly Understanding the Second-Level and Query Caches](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html)

Comment: The entities loaded by a query are cached as well, but the cache will only be hit if you find them by ID.